# How to check whether a variable is empty?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class dheepak():
    age = 23
    name = "dheepak sasi"

ankit = getattr(dheepak, "hostname", ' ')
if ankit == None:
    print "Shanaya"
else:
    print "byee"
mani = dheepak.age

print ankit
```

if hostname doesnot exist than it should print Shanaya if hostname present than print byee. And hostname value is coming from another program sometimes it comes sometimes not

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926446/how-to-check-whether-a-strvariable-is-empty-or-not

Answer (score 4):

You are supplying a space as the value for `ankit` if there is no such attribute, but checking for `None`. Be consistent:

```
ankit = getattr(dheepak, "hostname", None)
if ankit is None:
   ...
```

or

```
ankit = getattr(dheepak, "hostname", ' ')
if ankit == ' ':
   ...
```

Better yet, don't try to define a sentinel value at all; just catch the exception raised by `getattr` when the attribute doesn't exist.

```
try:
    ankit = getattr(dheepak, "hostname")
except AttributeError:
    print "Shanaya"
else:
    print "byee"
```

Comment: Since they don't need the attribute value, `hasattr` might be more appropriate.

Comment: I haven't done more than dabble with Python 3, so I still avoid `hasattr`. https://hynek.me/articles/hasattr/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
class dheepak():
    age = 23
    name = "dheepak sasi"

ankit = getattr(dheepak, "hostname", '')
if not ankit:
    print "Shanaya"
else:
    print "byee"
mani = dheepak.age

print ankit
```