# How to check if a string is different string constant (such as '\n', '\t') with Python

Tags: python, string

How to check if a String equals to Empty, and to a different string constant (such as '\n', '\t', etc.) with Python?

This is what I used:

```
if not text or text == '\n' or text == '\t':
    log.debug("param 'text': " + text)
    return None
```

how to do it better?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python

Comment: Not really a duplicate. The other question is specifically concerned with comparing against "".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if not text.rstrip():
  log.warning("Empty param 'text': " + text)
  return None
```

**str.rstrip([chars]):**
The method rstrip() returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the end of the string (default whitespace characters).

Answer (score 2):

```
if not text or text.isspace():
    # empty param text
```

Regarding `isspace`, it returns `True` if there are only whitespace characters and at least one character.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not text in (None, '', '\n','\t'):
```