# how to implement empty string in python

Tags: python, loops, string

I need to be able to prompt the user to enter an empty string so it can check if the answer is correct. but every time I do that I can error saying invalid literal for int() 
so I need to change my user_input so it can accept int() and strings(). how do I make that possible ?

```
# program greeting 
print("The purpose of this exercise is to enter a number of coin values") 

print("that add up to a displayed target value.\n") 

print("Enter coins values as 1-penny, 5-nickel, 10-dime,and 25-quarter.") 

print("Hit return after the last entered coin value.")

print("--------------------") 

#print("Enter coins that add up to 81 cents, one per line.")

import sgenrand

    #prompt the user to start entering coin values that add up to 81  
    while True: 
        total = 0 
        final_coin= sgenrand.randint(1,99)

        print ("Enter coins that add up to", final_coin, "cents, on per line") 

        user_input = int(input("Enter first coin: "))

        if user_input != 1 and user_input!=5 and user_input!=10 and user_input!=25:
        print("invalid input")

        else:
            total = total + user_input


        while total <= final_coin:
            user_input = int(input("Enter next coin:"))

            if user_input != 1 and user_input!=5 and user_input!=10 and user_input!=25:
                print("invalid input")                

            else:
                total = total + user_input


        if total > final_coin : 
            print("Sorry - total amount exceeds", (final_coin)) 

        elif total < final_coin:
            print("Sorry - you only entered",(total))

        else: 
            print("correct")    

        goagain= input("Try again (y/n)?:") 

        if goagain == "y":
            continue
        elif goagain == "n":
            print("Thanks for playing ... goodbye!" )
            break
```

Comment: If I copy and paste this code on my machine it won't work because all the indentation is messed up... can you fix the indentation so that the code runs?

Comment: @SethMMorton I just did, it should be good now

Comment: @SethMMorton ??? I finished editing it does it work now?

Comment: No.  Did you try copy and pasting what you have posted?  It will tell you where it still doesn't work.

Comment: @SethMMorton it works on mine

Comment: Nope, still doesn't.  Everything from the `while` loop onwards is still indented one level too deep.  Are you sure you are copying *from* this page and pasting that into your editor?  If so, it shouldn't work for you either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Store the value returned by `input()` in a variable.
2. Check that [the string is not empty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9573244/139010) before calling `int()`.

   - if it's zero, that's the empty string.
   - otherwise, try `int()`ing it.

Comment: im still new at this, uh how would you store the input as a variable cause I still need them to add up

Comment: @user2864064 You *are* storing input in a varible, i.e. `user_input = int(input("Enter next coin:"))`

Comment: @SethMMorton yeah that's what I'm doing