# Differences between two methods of checking for empty strings

Tags: python, string

What are the differences between the two methods?

```
if myString == ""

if not myString:
```

I read [Most elegant way to check if the string is empty in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9573244/3001761) before asking, but it doesn't clarify their differences.

Comment: I read the post before asking, in that post, it is not clarified their differences. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @jonrsharpe was trying to say it was wrong ended up writing that

Comment: @jonrsharpe, corrected my question. Your insights are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @VigneshKalai, corrected my question. Your insights are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa both does the same thing the `myString == ""` checks if string is empty explicitly `not myString` checks if string is empty implicitly

Comment: @LinMa by default `not ""` will be False like wise `not [],not 0,not {} etc..` but it is said to use `if myString == ""` because it is more readable

Comment: @VigneshKalai, nice catch, and if you could specify more what do you mean implicitly, it will be great. :)

Comment: @VigneshKalai, thanks for the inputs. For your comments about method of not "", what is the complete statement -- if myString not ""? It seems syntax is not correct?

Comment: @LinMa I believe they mean just `if not '':`, not actually referring to `myString` in that example

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I have two lines of code, which line do you mean? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both approaches will tell you, *given a string object `foo`*, whether it's an empty string or not:

```
>>> foo = ''
>>> foo == ''
True
>>> not foo
True
>>> foo = 'foo'
>>> foo == ''
False
>>> not foo
False
```

However, *given an arbitrary object `bar`*, you will get different results:

```
>>> bar = []  # empty list
>>> bar == ''
False  # isn't an empty string
>>> not bar
True  # but is still empty
```

Testing the truthiness works for many different kinds of object (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)), so `not x` will tell you whenever you have an *"empty"* object, but `x == ''` will only tell you whether or not you have an empty string. Which behaviour you need will depend on the situation you're in:

- if it's definitely a string and you want to know if it's an empty string, you can use either (but `not` is neater);
- if it's an arbitrary object and you want to know if it's an empty string, you need to use `== ''`; and
- if it's an arbitrary object and you want to know if it's empty, you need to use `not`.