# Check string "None" or "not" in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Wondering if `if not foo is None` is the same as `if foo`? Using Python 2.7 and `foo` is a string.

Comment: @Signal: No they are not. ``if foo is not None`` only checks if foo is really not the singleton ``None`` while ``if foo`` checks ``if bool(foo)`` or ``if foo.__nonzero__()`` which are completly different things.

Comment: @MSeifert, nice post, what does `if bool(foo)` and `if foo.__nonzero__()` means for strings in Python?

Comment: Whenever the ``len`` of a string is more than 0 ``bool(that_string)`` returns ``True``. If the ``len`` of the string is 0 then it returns ``False``. I think for the builtins like str there is no ``__nonzero__``-method, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up the names ... the method is called ``__bool__`` and not ``__nonzero__``.

Comment: @MSeifert, thanks and vote up. Do you mean there is only one method `__bool__` which is called if I use `if foo`?

Comment: I've uploaded my test, you can checkout this [gist](https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/19eb22199a8f035e5272).

Comment: @MSeifert, nice sample, I am wondering for any variable, what does `__bool__` do? I often see people are using `if not X` to check Null or not for any object.

Comment: every variable that is not empty (like an empty list/set/dict/string/...) or 0 (integer, float, ...) or simply ``False`` or ``None`` evaluates to ``True`` when used as ``if variable`` or ``if bool(variable)``

Comment: @MSeifert, a bit lost, do you mean `if None` return `True`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain it a bit further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most elegant way to check if the string is empty in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For empty strings both are different:

```
foo = ''
if foo:
    print 'if foo is True'
```

will not print anything because it is **empty** and therefore considered `False` but:

```
if foo is not None: 
    print 'if not foo is None is True'
```

will print because `foo` is **not None**!

I Changed it according to PEP8. `if foo is not None` is equivalent to your `if not foo is None` but more readable and therefore recommended by PEP8.

---

## A bit more about the general principles in Python:

```
if a is None:
    pass
```

The `if` will only be `True` if `a = None` was explicitly set.

On the other hand:

```
if a:
    pass
```

has several ways of evaluating when it is `True`:

1. Python tries to call `a.__bool__` and if this is implemented then the returned value is used.

   - So `None`, `False`, `0.0`, `0` will evaluate to `False` because their `__bool__` method returns `False`.
2. If `a.__bool__` is not implemented then it checks what `a.__len__.__bool__` returns.

   - `''`, `[]`, `set()`, `dict()`, etc. will evaluate to `False` because their `__len__` method returns `0`. Which is `False` because `bool(0)` is `False`.
3. If even `a.__len__` is not implemented then if just returns `True`.

   - so every other objects/function/whatever is just `True`.

See also: [truth-value-testing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in thy python documentation.

Comment: Avoid `not X is Y`, prefer `X is not Y`.

Comment: Thanks MSeifert, in Python any variable (could be string object and any other types of objects) should be point to something, correct? Then how could `if X is not None` be False?

Comment: MSeifert, nice answer. But how do we know for any class, if `__bool__` or `__len__` is defined?

Comment: ``help(a)`` shows you all information about the instance or just try ``print a.__bool__()`` or ``print a.__len__()``. (or the shortcuts ``bool(a)``, ``len(a)``) and see what raises an Error (then it's not implemented) or if it prints something (then it's implemented)

Comment: Nice idea MSeifert, vote up. I often see people write `if not X` (X could be any customized class types) to check if an object is Null or not, and I do not see if they defined `__bool__` or `len` object? Wondering if this writing style/method is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Ah forgot the obvious case: if none of those two methods is defined ``bool(a)`` just returns ``True`` regardless.

Answer (score 5):

No, not the same when foo is an empty string.

```
In [1]: foo = ''

In [2]: if foo:
   ...:     print 1
   ...:

In [3]: if foo is None:
   ...:     print 2
   ...:

In [4]: if not foo is None:
   ...:     print 3
   ...:
3
```

Comment: Thanks tianwei, vote up. I often see people write `if not X` (X could be any types of object), if in Python a variable have to point to some object, how could `if not X` be False? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa, when X is neither None nor empty(0,[], {}, () ,or ''), `if not X` would be False.

Answer (score 3):

Operator `is` compares ids (you can check the id of something with `id(something)`). As there is only one instance of `None`, any expression in the form `something is None` will be `False` except for `None is None` or if `something == None`. Operator `not` [has less precedence than comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) (and `is` is a comparison operator) so the result for `not string is None` which is the same as `not (string is None)` is **always `True`**.

Nevertheless a string object is considered `True` if it is not the empty string and `False` if it is the empty string.

So, one of the expressions is always `True` and the other can vary so no, they are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Salva, vote up. I often see people write `if not X` (X could be any types of object), if in Python a variable have to point to some object, how could `if not X` be False? Thanks.

Comment: And Salva, for `not str is None`, `not` is operate on `str`, or `not` is operated on `str is None`? Thanks.

Comment: `if not X` can be `False` because in the context where a boolean is expected such a if-test, `X` is converted into a boolean implicitly. The rules governing such conversions are summarized in the [Python online reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: @LinMa, answering to your second question I realized a failure in the answer reasoning. `not` has less precedence than comparisons so `not str is None` is the same as `not (str is None)`. I edit and fix the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Try this code

```
foo=''
if foo:
  print (1)
else:
  print (2)
if not foo is None:
  print (3)
else:
  print (4)
```

it will print

```
2
3
```

Comment: Thanks Sci, vote up. In Python any variable (could be string object and any other types of objects) should be point to something, correct? Then how could `if X is not None` be False?