# Understanding string "null" in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 variables: `x="null"` and `y=3`

Following which I execute the command below:

```
if(x and y):
  print 'True'
```

Output:`True`

I am looking for guidance to understand this behavior better.

The answer to this question fixed my issue [Most elegant way to check if the string is empty in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python)

But I want to understand the behavior of this. I want to know how an `AND` of `"null"` and a numeric value of `3` returns in `3` which in turn results in `truthify` value.

Comment: "null" is a string with value "null". Were you looking for `None` or `''`, the empty string?

Comment: Any non empty string can be considered as a `True` boolean value, in the same way that any int which is not `0`. So, `"null"` is just a string like any other, it is different from `None`.

Comment: The string `"null"` has no special significance in Python itself, although of course you are free to give it special significance in your own code. Note that the JSON module will translate `"null"` in a JSON object to `None`, and vice versa; thus `import json;print(json.loads('null'))` prints `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non empty string is always `True` in python. So `"null"` evaluates to `True` in a boolean operation, just as `"banana"`

Answer (score 2):

`""` is an empty string, `"null"` is not:

```
In[2]: bool("")
Out[2]: False
In[3]: bool("null")
Out[3]: True
```

Playing with the console to test your code behaviour is a good practice.