# How does this complex expression with OR work?

Tags: python

The line is:

```
key1 = dictionary_name.get('key1', ['']) [0] or 0
```

I understand the `get` method and the default value but I have no clue what's happening with the `or` after the `)`. The line seems to have the function to read the value of a key out of a directory and return `0` if the value is `' '`.
But how does the line, especially the boolean `or`, work in details?

Comment: If the zeroth element of the result of the `get` is falsy, the result will be `0`. Otherwise, use that element.

Comment: `or` is a lazy operator. If the first item is truthy, it'll return that. Otherwise it'll return the second value.

Comment: ...ahhh, now i understand... thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

The empty string is falsy in python, so in this situation, if key1 is not found, the value will be 0

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

[SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python)

Answer (score -1):

To quote the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is
>   returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is
>   returned.
>
> [...]
>
> Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return
>   to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument.