# How to check for empty JSON field in flask reqparse for a post request?

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-restful

I need to check for empty string in JSON field for a post request in flask using reqparse. Can I achieve it with flask reqparse module?

I have tried :

```
self.parser.add_argument('name', 
                 type=str, 
                 required=True, 
                 trim=True, 
                 location='json'
                )
self.parser.parse_args()
```

It is checking if the name field in `{"name":"xyz"}` is present, However I also want to check for empty values `{"name":""}` , so that I can throw error to user that name can not be empty. Is it possible to do that using reqparse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the [reqparse documentation](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/reqparse.html) and [how to check for empty strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python)
You could do something like...

```
args = self.parser.parse_args()
name = args['name']
if not name:
    # do your foo here if name is not truthy
```

Since `args['name']` can return an array, I'd be careful about the following edge cases.

```
[] == false
['foo'] == true
[' ', '   '] == true
```

So it might be better do something along the lines of

```
args = self.parser.parse_args()
names = args['name']
for name in names:
    if not name:
        # if not truthy
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def non_empty_string(s):
if not s:
    raise ValueError("Must not be empty string")
return s
parser.add_argument('name', required=True, nullable=False, type=non_empty_string)
```

i referred this from following  [link](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/741)