# Python: Comparing empty string to False is False, why?

Tags: python, string, boolean, logic

If `not ''` evaluates to `True`, why does `'' == False` evaluates to `False`?

For example, the "voids" of the other types (e.g. 0, 0.0) will return `True` when compared to `False`:

```
>>> 0 == False
True
>>> 0.0 == False
True
```

Thanks

Comment: empty sequence evaluates to `False`, but does not equal `False`. Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9573259/6313992 (top 2 answers cover this)

Comment: Thanks. Nevertheless, my question remains: Why?

Comment: @TonyPower Because this is how Python was chosen to be implemented. There's no real answer for the question "why". Also, why would an empty  list be *equal* to False? it is still a list, just an empty one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true. User-defined objects can customize their truth value by providing a `__bool__()` method.
>
> The operator `not` yields `True` if its argument is false, `False` otherwise.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons

But:

> The operators `<`, `>`, `==`, `>=`, `<=`, and `!=` compare the values of two objects. The objects do not need to have the same type.
>
> ...
>
> Because all types are (direct or indirect) subtypes of `object`, they inherit the default comparison behavior from `object`. Types can customize their comparison behavior by implementing rich comparison methods like `__lt__()` ...
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations

So, the technical implementation answer is that it behaves the way it does because `not` and `==` use different comparisons. `not` uses `__bool__`, the "truth value" of an object, while `==` uses `__eq__`, the direct comparison of one object to another. So it's possible to ask an object whether it considers itself to be *truthy* or *falsey*, and separately from that ask it whether it considers itself to be equal to another object or not. The default implementations for that are arranged in a way that two objects can both consider themselves *falsey* yet not consider themselves equal to one another.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't make sense for `''` and `[]` to actually equal `False`, because they are clearly different values: a string and a list. If they both equalled `False` they would have to be equal to each other*. They are just "falsey", which means they come out as false when they are converted to a boolean.

(* in any sensibly constructed language)

`not` is an operation that returns a boolean. Which boolean it returns depends on whether the operand is falsey or not. So `not x` is not equivalent to `x==False`; it is equivalent to `bool(x)==False`.

Comment: *cough* Behold PHP's logic: `[] == false; '' == false; [] != '';` Yup…

Comment: Hence my note at *

Comment: So, you are saying that it is not sensible to say that `''` is `False` but it makes sense to say that `0` is? I know boolean logic is all about zeroes and ones, nevertheless, it makes as much sense to me to say that `''` is `False` as it makes sense saying `not ''` is True.

Comment: The Python expression `'' is False` evaluates false, because `is` only returns True when the operands are references to the same object. `'' is True` also evaluates false, for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @TonyPower In Python `bool` is a subclass of `int`. This is not true of `list` or `str`. Basically `False` and `True` are just special instances of `0` and `1`. eg. `True + 2 == 3`, whereas `[] + 2` gives an error. If they are equal, then you need to be able to perform other types of operation with the strings and lists and ints.

Answer (score 1):

Such a comparison isn't "Pythonic" (*i.e.* it isn't what an experienced Python programmer would naturally do). The Pythonic way to proceed is to use a value in a Boolean context such as an `if` statement, and leave the interpreter to apply the `bool` built-in invisibly to determine a `True` or `False` value. That's why people commonly write code such as

```
if lst:
    print(headers)
    for item in lst:
        print(item.format())
else:
    print(no_data_message)
```

rather than using the commonly-seen but less Pythonic `if len(lst):` or the even clumsier but still functionally correct `if len(lst) > 0:`.

In some respects unfortunately, Python's designer decided that `True` and `False` would be instances of the `bool` type, and that `bool` would be a subclass of `int`. As a result of this `True` compares equal to `1` and `False` compares equal to `0`. Numerical conversion accounts for the floating-point (and, for that matter, complex) result.

But just because a `bool(x) == True` doesn't mean `x == True`, any more than `bool(x) == False` implies `x == False`. There are many other values that evaluate false, the best-known being

- Numeric zeroes
- `None`
- The empty string
- Empty containers (list, tuple, dict)

There's no way they can all be equal to each other!

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: This was the most valuable response for me in this question, since it actually explains *why* the `__eq__` operator behaves this way -- because bool is a subtype of int. That was the missing insight for me on this piece of Python's language design.

Answer (score 0):

Because `int(False) == 0` and `int(True) == 1`. This is what Python is doing when it tries to evaluate `0 == False`.

On the other hand, `bool('') == False`. The same goes for `bool([])` and `bool({})`.

The fact that `x` evaluates to `True` doesn't necessarily mean that `x == True`.

Comment: And if you switch things around? For example:

`False == 0`

Is it doing `False == bool(0)`?

If so, it should do the same with the empty string, and is not doing it.

Comment: "That is the reason that `is` should be used in checks against a boolean value and not `==`" -- I don't see how this follows

Comment: The tests `x is True` and `x is False` are, for most values of `x`, both False, so your advice that `is` should be used is dangerously wrong.

Comment: Also, understand the mechanism that is used. The interpreter applies the `bool` function to values.  `bool` returns either `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the [official explanation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), just cast your values like this:

```
print(bool(None) == False)
print(False == False)
print(bool(0) == False)
print(bool(0.0) == False)
print(bool(0j) == False)
print(bool('') == False)
print(bool(()) == False)
print(bool([]) == False)
print(bool({}) == False)
```