# Python - difference between an empty string and a string of spaces

Tags: python, string

To my amateur knowledge, an empty string is a string that has length zero. So that must differ from a string that is just spaces right? Even though printing both will appear the same.

I read here ([Most elegant way to check if the string is empty in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python)) how to recognize an empty string, but when running this bit of code on what I think is an empty string, it fails:

```
print("fish:", fish)

if not fish:       #if fish is empty string
    fish = weight
    print("new fish:", fish)
else:
    print("fish is not an empty string")
```

A printout of what `fish` is:

```
fish:
```

Am I missing something very simple here? Or is `fish` indeed a string of spaces and that's why the empty string search fails?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use ``print("fish: <{}>".format(fish))`` - then you would see ``fish: <  >``

Comment: It's really easy to accidentally mangle spaces when posting output like this, but from what we can see, it looks like your `fish` string has a single space in it.

Comment: i guess, you can probably use `fish.strip()` first.

Comment: Try `print(repr(fish))`. That'll add surrounding quotation marks.

Comment: Your code doesn't reproduce the problem.  Most of all, you did not supply values for `fish` and `weight`.  When I do so, `fish` finished with the value of `weight`, as expected.

Comment: It's possible that you have a non-printing character between the quotation marks.  Try re-typing your assignment to `fish`.

Comment: If you want to check if something is an empty string: `my_string == ''`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Why? [`if not my_string:` is perfectly valid/Pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573259/364696), and faster to boot. While `str` is a special case (in Py3, there aren't many, if any, "`str`-like" things that aren't equality compatible), I'm sick of seeing code that does `if myseq == []:` when they really want to know if it's an empty sequence, because it means you're now tied to an equality compatible type, and can't just substitute, say, `tuple`s without (silently) misbehaving.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I generally agree. That was for debugging purposes. I would use the `if fish` construction in the code, likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
print("fish:", repr(fish))
```

which will quote the output and use escapes for non-printable characters so you can see what's really in there. If it's anything other than `fish: ''`, it wasn't really empty. You could also just print `len(fish)`, which would give you the length; the definition of "falsy" for sequences is "length of 0" after all.

Comment: The output is `fish: ' ' `

Comment: @theprowler: Yeah, then you've got a single space character in there. If you want to ignore it, lead off with `fish = fish.rstrip()` to remove all trailing whitespace (which is usually not important to interpreting your value) or `fish.strip()` to remove both leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Ok gotcha. Is there a way to recognize if a variable is comprised of spaces? That way I can check if it's empty or if it's nothing but space?

Comment: @theprowler: `if not fish.strip():` would be the trivial test if you don't want to keep the stripped version. `if not fish or fish.isspace():` works without making a temporary string, but it's multiple tests and kind of ugly; the single test of `if not fish.strip():` is likely to be faster unless the strings involved are enormous.

Comment: That solved it. So I was pretty dumb, it was as simple as use `strip()` to remove all spaces, if any, then proceed. Well thanks a ton

Comment: @theprowler: To be clear, `strip` only removes leading and trailing whitespace. It won't remove internal whitespace. So `'   spam eggs   '.strip()` returns `'spam eggs'` (the space between the words is not removed).