# Replace blank spaces of a list

Tags: python, list

My script gives 2 string lists, `a` and `b` . I want to convert them to float lists to do some calculations, but the lists have some gaps. For example, i have  `a = ["1"," ","3","4"]` and i want to fill those gaps with 0 and have this `a = ["1","0","3","4"]`

Comment: `[1, ,3,4]` does not define a list.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Pretty sure he meant "1"," ","3","4". You should edit Wilson.

Comment: Where did the 'gaps' (empty strings?) come from, maybe you can stop them arising in the list in the first place

Answer (score 1):

```
a = list(map(lambda x: float(x) if x else .0, a))
```

Comment: If I understood him you probably want `float(x) if x`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list-comprehension.

```
a = ["1", " ", "3", "4"]

[float(i) if i.strip() else 0. for i in a]
# [1.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

The `strip()` part is to make `" "` `String` evaluated to `False`.

```
 >>> bool("")
 False
 >>> bool("   ")
 True
 >>> bool("   ".strip())
 False
```

[orginal source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573278/4530440)