# python using the "if" statement

Tags: python

Take in two numbers and a letter. If the letter is "a", the numbers will be added, if "s", subtracted, if "m", multiplied, and if "d", divided.

This is what I have:

```
num1 = int(input("please enter the first number"))
num2 = int(input("please enter the second number"))
lettler = input("please enter the operation")

a = int(num1 + num2)
s = int(num1 - num2)
m = int(num1 * num2)
d = int(num1 / num2)

if lettler + str(a):
    print(num1 + num2)
else:
    if lettler + str(s):
        print(num1 - num2)
    else:
        if lettler + str(m):
            print(num1 * num2)
        else:
            if lettler + str(d):
                print(float(num1) / num2)
```

But my professor is telling me it is wrong. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't need your professor to tell you this is wrong; simply running it would have done so.

Comment: how can i fix it, do I hv to use "elif" statement.

Comment: Fix it one line at a time and re-run to check if errors are going. Start with indentation.

Comment: num1 = int(input("please enter the first number"))
num2 = int(input("please enter the first number"))
operation = str(input("please enter the operation"))


a = int(num1 + num2)
s = int(num1 - num2)
m = int(num1 * num2)
d = int(num1 / num2)

if operation + str(a):
              print(num1 + num2)
elif operation - str(s):
              print(num1 - num2)

Comment: why just add the number, why is not subtracting

Comment: What exactly are your `if`s checking?

Comment: What do you expect the `lettler + str(a)` in your `if` to become?

Comment: when I type s I want to subtract, but is just working with the a

Comment: a should become num1 + num2?

Comment: @WilnnyAbreu: What do you expect `lettler + str(a)` to produce?  Under what circumstances would it ever be false?  If you were to *speak aloud* the condition you want to check in your `if` statements, what would that description be?  Do your `if` statements currently check that condition?

Comment: letter + str(A) if is false should ask you for the next letter

Comment: If the letter is "a", the numbers will be added, if "s", subtracted, if "m", multiplied, and if "d", divided.

Comment: @WilnnyAbreu: Yes, that's correct.  Now, under what circumstances *would it* be false?

Comment: @WilnnyAbreu: `"if the letter is 'a'"` - That's a good start.  Your `if` statements, however, are *not* checking that condition.  The condition you want to check is: "if letter equals 'a'".  How would you express that in code?

Comment: We understand what you want your code to do. We are trying to help you understand why it's wrong.  Klaus and David are hinting that `lettler + str(a)` will **never** be False.

Comment: @davi if one letter is false should ask you for the next letter?

Comment: letter == str(A)?

Comment: That's getting closer. What you want is `if letter == 'a':` and `elif letter == 's':` Etc.

Comment: @WilnnyAbreu: Why?  What would `str(a)` produce?  Put that exact operation in your code and output the result, observe what it produces.  Ask yourself *why* it would do that.  Ask yourself what the `a` variable is and where it comes from.  You have to think logically about this, you can't just type code-like things and expect the system to know what you mean.  Ask yourself, what is the difference between the variable `a` and the string `"a"`?

Comment: Side note, unrelated to the specific problem being faced... Currently your code produces all possible calculations and *then* attempts to determine which calculation to output.  This will fail spectacularly if anybody ever tries to add a zero to another number, an operation which *shouldn't* fail.  Don't perform the calculation until you determine what calculation the user asked you to perform.

Answer (score 6):

Your real problem here is that you're thinking out of order. You read the problem, and then started writing a solution before you *really* understood what it was asking for. That's actually really common to do when you see a big blob of text, and it takes practice and skill to go from there to a correctly working program.

Let's take this step by step:

> Take in two numbers and a letter. If the letter is "a", the numbers will be added, if "s", subtracted, if "m", multiplied, and if "d", divided.

Here's the assignment. Rather than leave it in this form, let's convert it to a form that's easier to think about piece by piece:

- Take in two numbers and a letter
- if the letter is 'a', the numbers will be added
- if the letter is 's', subtracted
- if 'm', multiplied
- and if 'd', divided

You'll notice that I didn't change any of the text here, I just shifted the formatting around. If you read the two, you'll see that there's no difference between them.

Now we can think about turning *that* into code, because it's layed out like code. You may have heard the term "pseudocode", which means "something that is code-like". We could even do that here.

```
#  Take in two numbers and a letter
num_one, num_two, letter = get_two_numbers_and_letter()

if letter is a:  # if the letter is 'a'
    print(num_one+num_two)   # the numbers will be added
if letter is s:  # if the letter is 's'
    print(num_one-num_two)   # the numbers will be subtracted
if letter is m:  # if 'm'
    print(num_one*num_two)   # multiplied
if letter is d:  # and if "d", divided
    print(num_one/num_two)
```

You'll notice that this already looks an awful lot like Python. We can clean it up a little:

```
# take in two numbers
num_one = int(input('First number: '))
num_two = int(input('Second number: '))
# and a letter
letter = input('(a)dd, (s)ubtract, (m)ultiply, or (d)ivide? ')

# if the letter is 'a', the numbers will be added
if letter == 'a':
    print(num_one + num_two)
# if the letter is 's', subtracted
if letter == 's':
    print(num_one - num_two)
# if 'm', multiplied
if letter == 'm':
    print(num_one * num_two)
# and if 'd', divided
if letter == 'd':
    print(num_one / num_two)
```

Of course *now* the comments are a bit superfluous - all they describe is exactly what the code is doing. We're also using `if` instead of `elif`, which is a bit ambiguous and less efficient (not that that really matters at this point, but it's still true). So let's clean up the code just a little bit more:

```
num_one = int(input('First number: '))
num_two = int(input('Second number: '))
letter = input('(a)dd, (s)ubtract, (m)ultiply, or (d)ivide? ')

if letter == 'a':
    print(num_one+num_two)
elif letter == 's':
    print(num_one-num_two)
elif letter == 'm':
    print(num_one*num_two)
elif letter == 'd':
    print(num_one/num_two)
else:
    print("I'm sorry, I don't recognize letter", repr(letter))
```

## Bonus - On Debugging

If your professor has not been teaching you about the REPL then they're doing you a disservice. The REPL is *great*, and especially for beginners. You can experiment and get feedback immediately. Let's consider part of your original code:

```
num1 = int(input("please enter the first number"))
num2 = int(input("please enter the second number"))
lettler = input("please enter the operation")

a = num1+num2

if lettler + str(a):
    print(num1 + num2)
```

You could just copy and paste this into the REPL, or even better, skip out on the input part, and just assign the values you want:

```
>>> num1 = 3
>>> num2 = 5
>>> lettler = 'a'
>>> a = num1 + num2
>>> if lettler + str(a):
...  print(num1 + num2)
...
8
```

Great! We got what we expected! But... that's not actually how you verify an experiment. You have to design something that should *fail*. So what if we try `lettler = 's'`?

```
>>> if lettler + str(a):
...  print(num1+num2)
...
8
```

Huh. Well, *that's* not right. We should have just got nothing. Luckily, this is pretty simple, it's just an `if` statement and a call to the `print` function. We know it's not the `print` that's the problem, our code never should have made it to that point. So let's check on what's in the `if` statement:

```
>>> lettler + str(a)
's8'
```

Oh. That's a string. Hm. It's not an empty string, and it's true. Maybe you remember this from class, but maybe you don't. So let's go to google and type in 'python why is my non-empty string true?'

When I do that the first result I get is https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573259/344286 Which does a pretty good job of explaining it, and better yet, it even links us to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) that tells us:

> By default, an object is considered true...
>
> Here are most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> ...
>   empty sequences and collections: `''`...

Ahh! So because our string is not empty (`'s8'`) it's going to evaluate to `True`! Well, okay. So what do we *actually* want to do instead? We probably don't want to be adding strings together. Can we compare things instead? What if we try `==`?

```
>>> lettler = 'a'
>>> lettler == str(a)
False
```

Hm. Well, that's not what we expected, was it? I guess let's see what the values are:

```
>>> lettler
'a'
>>> a
8
```

Oh. Well yeah, those aren't equal! And `a` isn't the letter `'a'`. Oh that's right! We said that `a = num1 + num2`, so of course it's not a letter. Maybe in the future we shouldn't use letters for variable names. If we take a step back and think about what we *want* (`if the letter is "a" the numbers should be added`) then we have the answer. We want to compare `lettler` to `"a"`:

```
>>> if lettler == 'a':
...  print(num1 + num2)
...
8
>>> lettler = 's'
>>> if lettler == 'a':
...  print(num1 + num2)
...
>>>
```

Ah. Perfect!

Answer (score 1):

An if statement works by testing if the expression you put after the `if` keyword is true. What you’re doing is adding two strings. In python, a string with characters will always come out to true, thus, the first if is always executed. What I have done is modify your conditions to match what you want:

```
num1 = int(input("please enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("please enter the second number: "))
lettler = input("please enter the operation: ")

if lettler == 'a':
    print(int(num1 + num2))
elif lettler == 's':
    print(int(num1 - num2))
elif lettler == 'm':
    print(int(num1 * num2))
elif lettler == 'd':
    try:
        print(float(num1 / num2))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('You tried to divide by zero')
```

See how I test if `lettler` (your operation input) is equal to the corresponding letter? That’s what you want. I also added a try/except that makes sure your program doesn’t crash if you divide by zero.

Comment: I knew that would happen, in fact I tested for it. I just wanted to preserve his code. I’ll edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = int(input("please enter the first number"))
num2 = int(input("please enter the second number"))
lettler = input("please enter the operation")

a = int(num1 + num2)
s = int(num1 - num2)
m = int(num1 * num2)
d = int(num1 / num2)

if lettler == "a":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif lettler == "s":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif lettler == "m":
    print(num1 * num2)
elif lettler == "d":
    print(float(num1) / num2)
```

Comment: That's almost correct, but you should get rid of that middle section from `a = int(num1 + num2)` to `d = int(num1 / num2)`. You don't need it, and you don't do anything with the values it calculates.

Comment: BTW, in Python 3 you don't need to do `float(num1) / num2`, you can just do `num1 / num2` and it will give the correct result.

Comment: @wilnnyadreu print a,b,c and d respectively not the operations they represent.