# how to fix ValueError :could not convert string to float: in Python

Tags: python, csv, readline

i have a python script that read from CSV file and  check if the records meet the conditions.

- if yes the system display the result
- if no  the system raise Exception based on the Error.

the csv file  includes a filed that has **float values**  but some of these records may not have any value so will be empty.

the problem is if the cell is empty the system display this ValueError :

```
could not convert string to float:
```

and not the Exception that i wrote it.

```
 raise Exception("this Record has empty value")
```

- row[0]==> Date type Date
- row[10]==> wind speed type float
- row[11]==> fog type boolean

## code:

```
import csv

mydelimeter = csv.excel()
mydelimeter.delimiter=";"
myfile = open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv")

# read the first line in the opened file ==> Header
myfile.readline()


myreader=csv.reader(myfile,mydelimeter)
mywind,mydate=[],[]
minTemp, maxTemp = [],[]
fastwindspeed, fog=[],[]

'''
create a variable that handle values of the 3 fields ==> Date - fastest5secwindspeed - fog
 and display the result where  
     fog ==> Yes    and highest speed  more than 10.
'''
for row in myreader:
    try:
        if row[11] =="Yes":
            if float(row[10]) < 10.0:
                raise Exception( 'the wind speed  is below 10 mph in ' + row[0] )
            if row[10] in (None, ""):
                raise Exception("this Record has empty value")

            print(row[0],row[10],row[11])
    except Exception as e:
        print("{}".format(e))

myfile.close()
```

Comment: Just test if it is empty **before** trying to convert it.

Comment: For example to check if it is empty see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python

Comment: @ThierryLathuille that what i am trying to do 
  if row[10] in (None, ""):
                raise Exception("this Record has empty value")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the order of your raises, also you should be handling the possibility of a non-float in that column:

```
import csv

mydelimeter = csv.excel()
mydelimeter.delimiter=";"
myfile = open("C:/Users/test/Documents/R_projects/homework/rdu-weather-history.csv")

# read the first line in the opened file ==> Header
myfile.readline()


myreader=csv.reader(myfile,mydelimeter)
mywind,mydate=[],[]
minTemp, maxTemp = [],[]
fastwindspeed, fog=[],[]

'''
create a variable that handle values of the 3 fields ==> Date - fastest5secwindspeed - fog
 and display the result where  
     fog ==> Yes    and highest speed  more than 10.
'''
for row in myreader:
    try:
        if row[11] =="Yes":
            if row[10] in (None, ""):
                raise Exception("this Record has empty value")
            try:
                if float(row[10]) < 10.0:
                    raise Exception( 'the wind speed  is below 10 mph in ' + row[0] )
            except ValueError:
                raise Exception('This Column expected to have a float has a non-float instead")

            print(row[0],row[10],row[11])
    except Exception as e:
        print("{}".format(e))

myfile.close()
```

Comment: thank you this was the problem the order of  the raise

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue during my project work. I just did like below:-

```
  if(len(row[10]) > 0):
      wind_speed = flot(row[10])
```