# SSH Tunnel using sshtunnel module not allowing empty password

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to start a ssh tunnel using sshtunnel module from Windows machine to Linux machine where my Linux machine has no password.

```py
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    '172.30.1.101',
    ssh_username="root",
    ssh_password="",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 1883)
)

server.start()
```

I keep on getting below error.

```
remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 1883)
  File "C:\Users\Chirag.Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py", line 905, in __init__
    logger=self.logger
  File "C:\Users\Chirag.Acharya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sshtunnel.py", line 1096, in _consolidate_auth
    raise ValueError('No password or public key available!')
ValueError: No password or public key available!
```

What to do! My ssh doesn't need any password! root user has no password set to login.

Comment: "My ssh doesn't need any password!" - then you probably use the key to log in. Attach your key as shown in the documentation.

Comment: I mean to say root user has no password set. I can login into root user without password

Comment: Allowing root without password is a frowned upon security practice. As `ssh` targets security the `sshd` server disallow root access by default, and AFAIK requires one valid authentication method, either password (with an existing password) or key, or remote machine key, maybe others but probably not an empty password.

Comment: I understand the risk of not using password for login. But this is the situation right now where I don't have to use any password. Actually this device is from other team and I can not force them to set password to the device.

Comment: Are you really sure that you do not need any authentication? Show us a log file from any SSH client showing how you login with the root account. + If you really need no authentication, did you try entering a dummy password or using a dummy key in your Python code?

Comment: I am not sure how will I show you logs! But I tried to set password for root user using `passwd` command and then above code worked fine with given password.
Then again to roll back I ran `passwd -d root` command to make sure I delete password for root user.

Also I tried to set some dummy value in `ssh_password` field but it failed.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am encountering the same problem. We're using a host with no authentication (there are other mechanisms in place to make sure that only authorized users can access it) and calling SSHTunnelForwarder with an empty password always gives the sshtunnel.BaseSSHTunnelForwarderError: Could not establish session to SSH gateway error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. But I know I connect with an empty password, as my paramiko ssh client is connected with an empty password. Is there a way to set up SSHTunnelForwarder with empty password ?

Comment: @GenevièveLeHoux nope sadly never found solution to this issue and gave up on that task finally

Answer (score 0):

### It is a *very* bad idea to configure *any* account, in *any* environment, with a blank password for SSH authentication. Please strongly consider the risks you're taking on with such a setup.

There is a reason that daemons like `sshd` do not enable this setup by default.

With that said...

---

The `sshtunnel` library does not (in its current iteration) support scenarios where the target system's SSH password is blank. This is because of [the way it performs checking on authentication information](https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel/blob/aa7342e55e49529fea020a09ba8f1eed33eb896f/sshtunnel.py#L1168-L1169):

```
if not ssh_password and not ssh_loaded_pkeys:
    raise ValueError('No password or public key available!')
```

Since [the blank string you've passed for `ssh_password` is "falsy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python), the library (correctly) throws this error.

If you're feeling brave, you could fork the repository and adjust this logic such that it explicitly allows blank strings to be passed as a valid SSH password:

```
if (not ssh_password and ssh_password != '') and not ssh_loaded_pkeys:
    raise ValueError('No password or public key available!')
```

After that, it would be a matter of [installing the forked branch over the current version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101834/pip-install-from-git-repo-branch). At that point, it would become your responsiblity to ensure any future changes in the upstream repository are merged to your fork, as those would no longer automatically propagate.