# check if row in json file is empty

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I use this code to read lines from json file and insert them in DynamoDB via Lambda:

```
obj= s3.get_object(Bucket=b, Key=jsonFile)
recList=obj['Body'].read().split('\n')
for row in recList:
    table.put_item(Item=json.loads(row))
```

After all lines are inserted, I get this error:

```
no json object could be decoded
```

I checked and found that my json file ends with an empty row. How can I correct my code by checking for each row if it is empty or not please? Or even better, ignore the last row as I am sure it is only the last line that is empty.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
obj= s3.get_object(Bucket=b, Key=jsonFile)
recList=obj['Body'].read().split('\n')
for row in recList:
  if row.strip():
    table.put_item(Item=json.loads(row))
```

Comment: thank you. it worked. But can you tell me what does strip do exactly? accoring to the documentation https://docs.python.org/fr/2.7/library/string.html#string.strip it Returns a copy of the string with leading and trailing characters removed. But here we are using it as a boolean

Comment: find a good discussion with backgrounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty)