# How to convert the empty string parsed from .txt file to None?

Tags: python

```
import os

pwd1 = str()
pwd2 = None
pwd3 = ""
pwd4 = " "

print("1:%s" %pwd1)
print("2:%s" %pwd3)
print("3:%s" %pwd3)
print("4:%s" %pwd4)
```

Test.txt file contents:

```
[Section1]
username : testuser
password : validpwd

[Section2]
username : testuser
password : validpwd

[Section3]
username : testuser
password : 

[Section4]
username : testuser
password : validpwd
```

`Section3` contains `password :` as empty line.

I have parsed the value of the "password" field from `Section3`, and when I tried to print the "password" value, it prints as empty line in output. I need it to mention it as "None". How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the string is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can check the length of password, while parsing. And if the length is <1, just assign it the value None.

```
psd = ''
psd = psd.strip()
if len(psd)<1:
    psd= 'None' # you can also just use None without any quotes
print(psd)
```

Comment: Maybe good to use `psd.strip()` to handle the case where it's just whitespace, ex. `psd = '   '`, which would still print a blank line.

Comment: @GinoMempin `print(None)` prints `None`. Only a bare `None` in the shell will give a blank line.

Comment: You  could shorten this to `psd = psd or None` ;-)

Comment: I appreciate the above two comments and can be incorporated for a more robust solution. Thank you guys. Cheers