# logical_and and np.where issue : Python Code Error

Tags: python, numpy

This is my actual requirement, and i tried to replicate in python by using either np.where(numpy) or logical operator(logical_and). but i got syntax error.

please help me to resolve the issues

**Actual logic:**

```
IF (AND ([Key] <> "", MATCHES ([Comments], "")), "To Be Assesed", IF ([Aging] = 0, "To Be Assesed", [Comments]))
```

**Python Code:**

logical_and:

```
Final_Output['Comments']= np.logical_and(Final_Output['Key']<>"",Final_Output['Comments']==""),"ToBeAssesed",np.where(Final_Output['Aging']=0,"ToBeAssesed",Final_Output['Comments'])
```

np.where:

```
Final_Output['Comments']= np.where((Final_Output['Key']<>'' , Final_Output['Comments']=''),'ToBeAssesed',np.where(Final_Output['Aging']=0,'ToBeAssesed',Final_Output['Comments']))
```

Thanks,
Sabarinathan.C

Comment: What is the syntax error you are receiving? Please post the full traceback.

Comment: is it the use of `<>` instead of `!=`?

Comment: File "<ipython-input-20-1e80b6f12f59>", line 46
    Final_Output['Comments']= np.where((Final_Output['Key']!='',Final_Output['Comments']=''),"ToBeAssesed",np.where(Final_Output['Aging']=0,"ToBeAssesed",Final_Output['Comments']))
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things mixed up and confused.

**First**, I advice to carefully read the [numpy where specs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). You will find, there is no possibility to pass [only two arguments](https://thispointer.com/numpy-where-tutorial-examples-python/) to numpy.where.

**Second**, you seem to compare empty / non-empty stings. In python an empty string results in boolean `false`. You can read about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty).

your definition of

```
Final_Output['Key']<>'' , Final_Output['Comments']=''
```

should read as

```
Final_Output['Key'], not Final_Output['Comments']
```

That even conforms to python's(3) syntax.

**Third**, mind the equal operations:

`=` is an assignment from right to left and it is a statement, not an expression. It therefore cannot be used in composed expressions. It will result in a syntax error

`==` is for testing equality between left and right and results in a boolen

**Fourth**, the diamond operator `<>` is dangerous (testing for inequality). Whether it works, depends on the version of python in use. In python 2 it does what you expect. But in python 3 it is not there any more and its use results in a syntax error. So you'd be better off using the statement given above (under "Second").

Mind that [python 2 is no more supported](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/). Future dev should be done with **python 3**.