# Understanding precedence of `not` operator

Tags: python, string, comparison

I tried to test empty string in Python (empty string should be "Falsy" as they write in: [How to check if the string is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty)). However I used a little bit different syntax and get weird result in the following comparison:

```
not(''); # result: True

not('hello'); # result: False

not('hello') == False; # result: True

not('hello') == True; # result: True - how is this result possible? (False == True: result must be False)
```

Thank you for the answer!

Comment: FWIW, the `()` and `;` are very superfluous…

Comment: `not` negates a boolean value. Empty strings are Falsy. not Falsy is True.  - Non-empty strings are Thruthy, not Truthy is flase. `not` is no function - the ( ) is your doing. `not (hello) == True` is equal to `not ( "hello" == True)`

Answer (score 2):

The precedence here is `not ('hello' == False)`. `'hello'` equals neither `True` nor `False`, so both `'hello' == True` and `'hello' == False` are `False`, which is then negated by `not`.

```
>>> 'hello' == False
False
>>> 'hello' == True
False
>>> not ('hello' == True)
True
```

Truthiness isn't the same as *being equal to `True`*. A string can be *truthy* (i.e. you can decide whether it's more of a "yes" or a "no"), but at the same time not be *equal to* a boolean value (because a string is a string and a boolean is a boolean).

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand that `not` is an *operator*, not a *function*. The parenthesis do nothing for the expression, here's how it is read:

```
not('hello') == True
# is the same as
not 'hello' == True
# which is the same as
not ('hello' == True)
# which is equivalent to 
not False
# which is 
True
```

Which happens to evaluate to the same as the expression above (for the same reason that `'hello' == False` is `False`.

The correct way of enforcing precedence with `not` would be to do

```
(not something) == True
```