# Check if a string is empty

Tags: python

Trying to say in my code that if `middle_name` is an empty string then print, else if it has been inputted then print the second way.

What's the best way to word my if statement?

```
first_name = input()
middle_name = input()
last_name = input()

first_initial = first_name[0:1]
middle_initial = middle_name[0:1]
  
      
if middle_name != str:
    print((last_name + ','), first_initial)
else:   
    print(last_name,(first_initial + '.' + middle_initial + '.'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the string is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty)

Comment: @greenjaed yes thank you, I ended up scrapping this idea and went with something different, but thank you anyways