# How to write a response if there is no input in one of the variables

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a Python program that gets login credentials from the user and then outputs a message if the credentials are correct. I am trying to output a response if the both the input fields are empty. My code:

```
username = "user123"
passw = "password"
print("Welcome to YourSpace! Please login below")
    
login_name = input("Please Enter your username: ")
login_pass = input("Please Enter your password: ")
    
        
if login_name == username and login_pass == passw:
    print("Successful Login! Welcome to YourSpace!")
        
if login_name != username and login_pass == passw:
    print("Invalid username. Please refresh and try again.")
        
if login_name == username and login_pass != passw:
    print("Invalid password. please refresh and try again.")
        
if login_name != username and login_pass != passw:
    print("Invalid username and password. Please refresh and try again")`
```

Any help for my problem is welcome.

Comment: Where is your attempt at doing this?

Comment: Storing your passwords in your code is a bad idea. Consider using [hashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) with a salt.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if the string is empty in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/how-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

use double qouts:

```
myName = input("say my name...")


if myName == "Jack":
    print("Thats right!")

elif myName == "":
    print("its empty! write something!!")

else:
    print("Thats incorrect!")
```

for yours, will be:

```
if login_name == "" or login_pass == "":
    print("username and password cannot be empty!")`
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# (your code...)
if not login_name or not login_pass:
    print("One of the inputs is empty. Please refresh and try again.")
```

In Python, `not <string>` is `True` only when the string is empty, so it's equivalent to `<string> == ""`.

Answer (score 0):

To handle empty inputs, you can check if the input strings are empty before comparing them. Here's an updated version of your code:

```py
username = "user123"
passw = "password"
print("Welcome to YourSpace! Please login below")

login_name = input("Please Enter your username: ")
login_pass = input("Please Enter your password: ")

if not login_name or not login_pass:
    # Check if the inputs are empty
    print("Username and password are required. Please refresh and try again.")

elif login_name == username and login_pass == passw:
    print("Successful Login! Welcome to YourSpace!")

elif login_name != username and login_pass == passw:
    print("Invalid username. Please refresh and try again.")

elif login_name == username and login_pass != passw:
    print("Invalid password. Please refresh and try again.")

else:
    print("Invalid username and password. Please refresh and try again.")
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the inputs are empty, you can just use empty quotes. Modified code:

```
username = "user123"
passw = "password"
print("Welcome to YourSpace! Please login below")

login_name = input("Please Enter your username: ")
login_pass = input("Please Enter your password: ")
   
if login_name == username and login_pass == passw:
    print("Successful Login! Welcome to YourSpace!")
    
if login_name != username and login_pass == passw:
    print("Invalid username. Please refresh and try again.")
    
if login_name == username and login_pass != passw:
    print("Invalid password. please refresh and try again.")
    
if login_name != username and login_pass != passw:
    print("Invalid username and password. Please refresh and try again")`

if login_name == "" or login_pass == "":
    print("All the fields should be filled.")
```

However, it is not a good idea to let the user know if either the login or the password is correct. Modified code for the same:

```
username = "user123"
passw = "password"
print("Welcome to YourSpace! Please login below")

login_name = input("Please Enter your username: ")
login_pass = input("Please Enter your password: ")

if login_name == username and login_pass == passw:
    print("Successful Login! Welcome to YourSpace!")

if login_name != username or login_pass != passw:
    print("Invalid username or password. Please refresh and try again")

if login_name == "" or login_pass == "":
    print("All the fields should be filled.")
```

To make it better, you can check if the credentials are correct only if the strings aren’t empty. Example code:

```
username = "user123"
passw = "password"
print("Welcome to YourSpace! Please login below")

login_name = input("Please Enter your username: ")
login_pass = input("Please Enter your password: ")

if login_name != "" and login_pass != "":
    if login_name != username or login_pass != passw:
        print("Invalid username or password. Please refresh and try again")

    elif login_name == username and login_pass == passw:
         print("Successful Login! Welcome to YourSpace!")   

else:
    print("All the fields should be filled.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue by checking for an empty string or if the string is falsey. In the below example we use the falsey approach. However, all of this should be in a loop that will only break once the proper information is inserted. Also, your conditions can be refactored completely out of existence with some simple bit-shifting.

```
username = "user123"
password = "password"

print("Welcome to YourSpace! Please login below")

#tradeoff - this instead of repetitive conditions and processes
WHICH    = ('', 'username', 'password', 'username and password')
REQUIRED = ('username', 'password')

while True:
    #for storing initial input
    userdata = []
    
    #loop required fields checking for empty input
    for field in REQUIRED:
        if not (item := input(f"Please enter your {field}: ")):
            #no data, start over
            print(f'{field.title()} cannot be empty. Please try again.')
            break
            
        #store non-empty input
        userdata.append(item)
    else:
        n, p = userdata      #unpack user input
        n    = n != username #username fail fact
        p    = p != password #password fail fact
        fail = p << 1 | n    #WHICH index, if 0 no errors
        
        #proper data
        if not fail:
            print("Successful Login! Welcome to YourSpace!")
            break
        
        #specific reason for failing
        print(f"Invalid {WHICH[fail]}. Please try again.")
```

As much as it may seem like giving a user a specific reason why the login failed is a good idea, it's actually a bad one. Not all of your user will have the best intentions. If they are guessing usernames or passwords, you are telling them exactly which one they got wrong. It also doesn't matter which one the user got wrong because, they are going to have to input all of the information fresh, anyway. Simply saying something like "Incorrect Login Information. Please try again." is a better way to go. Putting a cap on how many times they can try within a certain amount of time is another good idea. That being said, the below is leaning towards a better design.

```
username = "user123"
password = "password"

print("Welcome to YourSpace! Please login below")

REQUIRED = ('username', 'password')

for i in range(1,6):
    #for storing initial input
    userdata = []
    
    #loop required fields checking for empty input
    for field in REQUIRED:
        userdata.append(input(f"Please enter your {field}: "))
        
    #proper data
    if userdata == [username, password]:
        print("Successful Login! Welcome to YourSpace!")
        break
    
    #non-specific reason for failing
    print(f"Invalid Login Credentials. You have {5-i} attempts left.")
else:
    print('All of your attempts failed. You must wait 15 minutes before trying again.')
```

You have another problem, though. In this case the username and password are hard-coded so you know both before-hand. That's never going to be the case in a real world scenario. All this checking usernames and passwords like it's the most intuitive system to ever exist is not even going to be close to what you will really need to do.